# How to interconvert InChI and InChIKey?

Tags: python, web-services, bioservices

I would like to retrieve IDs from several databases using `InChI` as an input, e.g.

```
InChI=1S/C6H14N2O2/c7-4-2-1-3-5(8)6(9)10/h5H,1-4,7-8H2,(H,9,10)/t5-/m0/s1
```

One can use [unichem](https://pythonhosted.org/bioservices/_modules/bioservices/unichem.html) from `bioservices` for this, however, these functions all require the `InChIKey` as input, e.g.

```
KDXKERNSBIXSRK-YFKPBYRVSA-N
```

Is it possible to interconvert the two using `bioservices` and if not is it possible to somehow use the functions in `unichem` with `InChI` rather than the `InChIKey`?

I tried:

```
from bioservices import *
u = UniChem()
u.get_src_compound_ids_from_inchikey('KDXKERNSBIXSRK-YFKPBYRVSA-N')
```

which works fine, however,

```
u.get_src_compound_ids_from_inchikey('InChI=1S/C6H14N2O2/c7-4-2-1-3-5(8)6(9)10/h5H,1-4,7-8H2,(H,9,10)/t5-/m0/s1')
```

does not work and returns `400`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if directly possible in `bioservices` but one can do the following workaround using [chemspider](https://www.chemspider.com/InChI.asmx):

```
import requests

host = "http://www.chemspider.com"
getstring = "/InChI.asmx/InChIToInChIKey?inchi="
inchi = 'InChI=1S/C6H14N2O2/c7-4-2-1-3-5(8)6(9)10/h5H,1-4,7-8H2,(H,9,10)/t5-/m0/s1'

r = requests.get('{}{}{}'.format(host, getstring, inchi))
if r.ok:
    res = str(r.text.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<string xmlns="http://www.chemspider.com/">', '').replace('</string>', '').strip())
else:
    print "provide a valid inchi!"
```

This will give the desired InChIKey

```
'KDXKERNSBIXSRK-YFKPBYRVSA-N'
```

which can be used in `unichem`.